# What is the performance cost to running BitLocker?

Tags: windows, performance, bitlocker

BitLocker encrypts the entire hard drive. I run [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) and build projects much of my day. How much will BitLocker slow me down (dual core laptop with 3 GB of RAM)?

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/q/235420/89990

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[MaximumPC](http://www.maximumpc.com/) ran a few tests:

> However, when we busted out the
>   hard-drive-intensive benches, we
>   immediately saw as much as a 20
>   percent hit on the encrypted system.
>   We're not sure the PCMark06 slowdown
>   represents real-world performance, but
>   our Photoshop script, which includes
>   tons of hard-drive-intensive reverts,
>   showed a 10 percent hit as well.
>
> What's the bottom line? We're not
>   going to enable BitLocker on systems
>   that don't hold crucial,
>   mission-critical data.

Benchmark (Unencrypted Drive; Encrypted Drive):

> FEAR (FPS); 56; 57
>
> 3dMark06; 8071; 8082
>
> PCMark06 Hard Drive Suite; 6133; 4948
>
> Photoshop CS Script (Sec); 303; 330

Sure, running 3D benchmarks doesn't really make sense as you're hardly going to encrypt a gaming rig, but in the end it's simple trade-off: performance for security.

Comment: newer BitLocker version have better performance