# Bitlocker with 2 SSDs in RAID 0 - Does TRIM function?

Tags: ssd, encryption, bitlocker, raid-0, trim

I've found that in Windows 7 and 8 if you have one of the newer versions of Intel Rapid Storage Technology the TRIM command is passed to SSDs in a RAID configuration (see here for example https://superuser.com/a/140311/68237)

What I have been unable to find information on is if this is still true if you use Bitlocker to encrypt the RAID 0 volume. Even if it was supported would TRIM even work if the volume is encrypted? I am wondering if the OS or Bitlocker gives any indication of what is free space and what is not because if it doesn't wouldn't that pretty much prevent TRIM from doing anything?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?  You have to unlocked the drive to view the contents of the drive, at that point, Window's behavior toward the encrypted volume, would match that of any other volume.

Comment: I thought that "unlocking" the drive doesn't decrypt the entire drive. If that was the case wouldn't the process take a very long time for large drives? Doesn't Bitlocker do encryption/decryption on the fly? I'm thinking if the OS goes to TRIM the drive it will be unable to see anything as garbage that it can collect...

Comment: All I know is that Microsoft operating systems support TRIM.  They also support encrypting disks that would require that TRIM support.  Have you confirmed this is even a problem or you just asking?

Comment: I have not confirmed it. Just trying to get the most information I can before I go ahead and do it.

Comment: All I know is my Bitlocker encrypted drive shows all files in windows explorer, which means the drive was decrypted, I think you are worring over nothing.  Microsoft's own suggestion is to use BItlocker on SSD's which means TRIM would be supported.  Here is a discussion on the topic [here](http://superuser.com/questions/235420/bitlocker-performance-impact-on-ssd) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/02bf1f74-092c-42f2-9888-c8ef43ab1c19/bitlocker-on-ssd-drives-with-trim)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Looks like I should be good. I still don't think Bitlocker decrypts the whole drive. If it takes over 24 hours to encrypt a 4 TB hard drive there's no way it could decrypt all 4 TB instantly. It must be on the fly handled by low level drivers. My biggest worry about TRIM not being supported was the lifespan of my SSDs. While the reduced speed might not be a big deal having no wear leveling in place is a big concern for me.